# Vs code python, no module found

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to get vs studio working with python 3.7 and when I go to load numpy, it says "no module found". What's the best way to fix this?

Comment: Have you actually isntalled `numpy` via `pip` or package installation yet on your Python system?  If not, that's why you're getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

You can install numpy package with:

```
pip install numpy
```